# Passing Parameter to SQL from Batch File - Garbage Value Appears

Tags: batch-file, parameter-passing, sqlplus

I am trying to pass parameters to SQL script as mentioned here. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834548/pass-parameters-from-a-batch-file-to-sqlplus-script)

This is my batch file.

```
testUpdate.bat

@echo off
sqlplus myuser@mydb/mypassword @updateRundate 25042018
pause
```

This is my sql file

```
updateRundate.sql

update SB_ER_RUNDATE set rundate = TO_DATE( '&1', 'ddmmyyyy');
commit;
exit;
```

I am getting the following error

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

old   1: update SB_ER_RUNDATE  set rundate = TO_DATE( '&1', 'ddmmyyyy')
new   1: update SB_ER_RUNDATE  set rundate = TO_DATE( 'to', 'ddmmyyyy')
update SB_ER_RUNDATE  set rundate = TO_DATE( 'to', 'ddmmyyyy')
                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected



Commit complete.
```

Instead of the passed parameter, garbage value is appearing in the query. Please help me to resolve this issue.

**Update**

The path of my sqlplus installation is

```
C:\app\nt to de softwares\product\11.1.0\client_1
```

I have observed that, if I am outputting &3 instead of &1, I am getting the value as 
`softwares\product\11.1.0\client_1\product\11.1.0\client_1\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql`

&1 outputs the value of 'to' . This is in fact part of the installation path.

**Update 2**
I have tried the second answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474899/default-value-for-paramteters-not-passed-sqlplus-script?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). The strange thing is that this script is not working in my system and it prints 'to' at the position of the parameter. But the same is working in another PC which has the same SQL plus installation.

Comment: Out of interest, why use `sqlplus myuser@mydb/mypassword @updateRundate 25042018` as opposed to `sqlplus myuser/mypassword@mydb @updateRundate.sql 25042018`?

Comment: Both are working for me. I was doing trial and error in different ways taking different examples to make this work. It just ended up this way in my last trial.! Thanks for stopping in...

Comment: Where is `updateRundate.sql` located? Or I suppose what location is set as `SQLPATH`. And did you try simply doublequoting the script name, `sqlplus myuser/mypassword@mydb @"updateRundate" 25042018`.

Comment: The sql file and bat file are located in the same folder. Tried doblequoting, it produces the same results. How to find my SQLPATH? There is no such environment variable set. Few months back, I had messed up with my environment variable in my system. can this be the cause?

Comment: In Windows `SQLPATH` is set in the registry, it is the location(s) used as a script repository, _if not found there the current working directory is searched_. I think by default it uses the location `%ORACLE_HOME%\DBS`. We know that your installation location has spaces, therefore the default script location will also have! Given that your batch file and sql file reside in the same location it may be a good idea to ensure that your current working directory is that of the batch file, a new line will sort that, `CD /D "%~dp0"`. BTW, the likely registry location is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Oracle\Home0`.